# Meaning of %||% in R

Tags: r, roxygen2

Found in roxygen2 code the shortcut :

```
%||%
```

No help can be found with

```
?"%||%"
```

It looks like a shortcut for `union()` but how could I display it's definition ?

Comment: You'll find such constructs throughout Hadley's (and other folks') packages, too. Highly efficient syntax shortcuts. Def worth digging. You can also find out where that's defined in any installed pacakges via `getAnywhere("%||%")` and then see the source for any of them by indexing that with `[]` (i.e. `getAnywhere("%||%")[1]`). In this case they all define it the same way, but it may not be the case in all packages. I know you only needed to see the definition from `roxygen2` ;-)

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) for such questions in general

Answer (score 4):

From source (`utils.R` from [`roxygen2_4.1.1.tar.gz`](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/roxygen2_4.1.1.tar.gz))

```
"%||%" <- function(a, b) {
  if (!is.null(a)) a else b
}
```

Comment: (i hope this is trivial, but just in case: if `a` is not null, then return `a` otherwise return `b`)